# how to call a method from a class in python

Tags: python, tkinter

How do I call the method `bio_info` from the class `Acceptor` in this code below?

```
import sys
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *
from tkMessageBox import *
from tkSimpleDialog import *


class Acceptor():

    def bio_info(self):

    #this method takes in input from the keyboard console

        def__init__(self,name,mat_no,semester)
        self.name=name
        self.mat_no=mat_no
        self.semester=semester


        Label(top,text='Name').grid(row=0)
        Label(top,text='Matric No').grid(row=1)
        Label(top,text='Semester').grid(row=2)

        name=Entry(top)
        mat_no=Entry(top)
        semester=Entry(top)


        name.grid(row=0,column=1)
        mat_no.grid(row=1,column=1)
        semester.grid(row=2,column=1)

        return name
        return mat_no
        return semester    


main = Tk()

#This defines the size of the main window
main.geometry('640x480')

    #This takes care of the configuration of the main window, buttons and labels inclusive
main.title('Result Calculator App')
mainLabel=Tkinter.Label(main,text='Result Calculator',bd=10, relief=RIDGE,fg='cyan')
mainLabel.pack(fill=BOTH)
mainLabel.config(font=('algerian',35, 'bold'), bg='blue',fg='orange')
calculate=Button(text="CALCULATE",font=('joan',20,'bold'),bg='black',fg='green',width=15,cursor='hand2',relief=SOLID,
command=Acceptor.bio_info)
calculate.pack()


print'This program ran correctly'
main.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why does your `__init__` *return things?*

Comment: your `__init__` is inside the bio_info method when it should be a method of Acceptor.
if you want to call bio_info as a class method, then decorate it with @classmethod and change the self parameter to cls, otherwise construct an instance of Acceptor, pass it the values you expect in `__init__` and call bio_info on your instance

Comment: Thanks for the observation and correction. It was a mistake

Answer (score 0):

You call it like you call any other method in any other class in python. You create an instance of the class, then call the method on the instance:

```
acceptor = Acceptor()
...
calculate=Button(..., command=acceptor.bio_info, ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make an instance of the class and call the method from that instance. Example:

```
myAcceptor = Acceptor()
myAcceptor.bio_info()
```

Answer (score 0):

As teckydesigner said, you need to make an instance of your class before you can use it.
 Your code `command = Acceptor.bio_info` won't compile because bio_info is a method and needs to be called like: `myAcceptor.bio_info()`.